# Eclipse include paths with virtual directories

Tags: c++, eclipse, unit-testing, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-juno

I have a C++ project in Eclipse Juno and I'm using the Boost Unit Test Framework. I am new to formal Unit Testing, so I am still working on my workflow.

My workspace contains two projects:

(1) my C++ Project

(2) unit test project to test the classes in (1)

As I write each unit test I import the necessary directories and files from (1) into (2) as *virtual directories*.

This works OK for the source files, but it doesn't seem to work for the header files.

e.g. compiling unit_test.cpp with

`#include "foo/bar.h"`

returns

`../unit_tests.cpp:8:30: error: foo/bar.h: No such file or directory`

even though there is a *virtual directory* `foo` with `bar.h` in it.

If I use the Eclipse "Open Declaration" command (F3) on: `#include "foo/bar.h"` it will open the file, but the compiler can't find the file because it doesn't actually exist in the folder (I guess).

I noticed that the compiler compiles the "real" source files with a non-virtual directory path, but obviously this isn't done automatically for the header files.

I solved my problem by adding a Workspace referenced include path to the compiler. e.g.
`${workspace_loc:/my C++ Project}` and this solved the problem, but what was the point of having virtual files when I have to create a reference to a real file anyway?

My questions are:

(*) Is this a good work flow?

(*) How can my workflow be improved?

(*) How do other people use Eclipse/IDEs to manage unit tests?